# ruby on rails - test for specific phone number of digits

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

This is my code

```
test 'phonenumber should be 11 digits' do
  @user.phonenumber = 11
  assert_not @user.valid?
end
```

this is my model validations, i am using the gem phonelibs

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  before_save { email.downcase! }
  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
  validates :phonenumber, phone: { possible: true, allow_blank: true }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-]+(\.[a-z\d\-]+)*\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 256 },
                    format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
  has_secure_password
  validates :password, presence: true, length: { minimum: 6 }
end
```

this already added the validations because it uses the  Google libphonenumber and for Nigeria, it is 11

```
Phonelib.default_country = 'NG'
```

but it isnt testing for the exact digits of phone number

Comment: Can you post your model validations please?

Comment: I have updated the question with the model validations

Answer (score 0):

You've used a couple of length validations elsewhere - I'd suggest you need the same for your `phonenumber` field before it will fail validations for being too short.

I.E.

`validates_length_of :phonenumber, is: 11`

or

`validates :phonenumber, length: { is: 11 }`

or using a regex:

`validates_format_of :phonenumber, with: /[0-9]{11}/`

Docs can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#length) - hope that helps!

`PhoneLib` has a lot of extra functionality based on countries and their phone number formats - the *best* approach here would be to dig properly into that and use their validations based on either a fixed or user-based location.

However, the above should work for ensuring the length of the `phonenumber` is 11.

---

Update:

The gem has a number of methods for checking validity of phone numbers, such as the following:

`Phonelib.valid? '123456789'`

`Phonelib.valid_for_country? '123456789', 'XX'`

You also need to configure the gem in `config/initializers/phonelib.rb` - if you could add that code to your question that would be useful.

However, to make use of this, your test could look something like:

```
test 'phonenumber should be 11 digits' do
  @user.phonenumber = 11
  assert_not Phonelib.valid?(@user.phonenumber)
end
```

Comment: Yes i understand you, the phonelibs gem already added that validation somehow, so i wanna test for it that a user must input only 11 digits, not less, not more, not sure of the test code i have up there

Comment: Thanks - I've updated my answer to reflect this. Hope it helps @InioluwaAkinleye

Comment: Thank you @SRack, but the test isnt still failing when i add, say 12 or 13. It still passes

Comment: Just to be clear - `12345678999` should be valid, right? You'll need to dig into `phonelib`'s docs to figure out what it's doing; it's likely the location you've got it setup for accepts shorter and / or longer numbers as valid (i.e. with area codes, countries etc.). If you're intent on it being fixed at 11 digits' length, just add an extra validation as in my answer. (Although correctly implementing their validations is probably the correct way to go.)